# git doesn't recognize my local changes

Tags: git, github

I am using an upstream repo that is forked from my GitHub repo.

I recently pushed, but since then i've had to repoint my upstream repo to the master branch.

After that, I now have a file that has some changes, and the same file on the upstream repo does NOT show those changes, but

```
git status
```

says everything is up to date. how can i get GIT to see that i've made changes on this file, and sync it when i do a push to the upstream? thanks

ps-i've searched for answers in stack overflow using google, but there are too many ambiguous/common words in my problem which obfuscates the results.

Comment: What do you mean by "upstream repo"? To which of the two repositories did you push? What do you mean by "repoint my upstream repo to the master branch" (a repository does not point to a branch)?

Comment: yeah, sorry i'm still fairly new to git. i pushed to my repo that i forked from the original repo in GitHub. I had an issue where i had accidentally pushed to the wrong branch in my forked repo, so i deleted that remote branch, then repointed to the master branch on that repo, and pushed to the master branch. I'm not sure if that even has anything to do with it, but i've only seen this weird behavior since then, so i'm thinking it might

Comment: So now the change you did to the file is included in the master branch of your forked repository on GitHub, but not included in the original repo you forked from, and you wonder why. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: the opposite, when i look on my local branch i still see the changes. However, when i look at the file on the forked repo I don't see those changes. However, "git status" says "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'."

Comment: strangely enough, i went to Visual Studio Code. there was a small red line indicating a change had been made (but it wasn't showing up on GIT). So, i reverted that change and then reapplied the change manually, and it LOOKS like it's fixed now... weird. whatever git.....

Comment: Have you done `git fetch <your_forked_upstream_repo>` in your local repo? Maybe the remote tracking branch in your local repo could be out of date (if you did any changes through some github web UI which interacts directly with the remote repo). Remote tracking branches (e.g. `origin/master` or `<your_forked_upstream_repo>/master` or `<your_forked_upstream_repo>/<your_task_branch>`) are updated only when you do `git fetch` (or `git pull`, which includes a fetch).